# What are the drawbacks of multiple Redis Instances on same machine?

Tags: linux, redis

We have a legacy system where instead of using multiple DB in a Redis instance, we are using multiple Redis instances(identifying by port number that they are running on) on the same machine with the default DB=0.

I want to convince everyone to put in effort and start using single Redis instance with different DB.

What can be some arguments in the favor of using single instance with multiple DB rather than multiple instances on default(single) DB=0?

There is no authentication process involved, which could have been one point in favor of multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases.
Multiple Redis instance on the same machine is the way to go.